# Which is the best place for parameter restrictions - inside or outside function?

Tags: c

Option 1: In function

```
int funcA(int a){
    if(a < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        ...
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Option 2: In main

```
int main(){
    int a;
    ...
    if(a < 0){
        ...
    }
    else{
        funcA(a);
    }
}
```

Option 3: Both places? If you have some suggestions I will be grateful.

Comment: There is nothing wrt "functional programming" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule as to what is better -- there's basically two cases you'd want to consider.

If the constraints are unique to this specific usage of the function, then it would be preferable to put them outside the function, to let the function be more generalized and limit only this specific call to it.

If the constraints are something integral to the function and are always going to be expected whenever the function is called, then it would be preferable to put them inside the function, so that they do not have to be duplicated every place that the function will be called.

Answer (score 1):

It is the *callers responsibility* to make sure it calls a function with valid arguments - per the documentation.

It is the called functions interest to guard against invalid values *when* it can - and again, per the documentation.

There is no inherently "right" or "wrong" choice *without* a contract (documentation) for `funcA` which is highly dependent on *what* the function does and *how* it is expected to be used.

Comment: That doesn't really give advice though to the person who's writing the functions -- obviously you can say everything is 'per the documentation' but if you're the one writing the documentation, you need to make the call on what happens inside vs outside your function.

Comment: @sphanley The advice to take away is *define a contract* (based on the *what* and *how*), specify it in documentation, and ensure that both the caller and the callee adhere to it. There is no "better" without rules for what is acceptable/excepted behavior.